# Changing values of 2d array

Tags: python

there is a random 2D array like

```
 A = [[312,13,344],[341,123,4343],[1,314,531]]
```

and i'd like to change values of 1st array,

```
 [[1,1,1],[341,123,4343],[1,314,531]]
```

there is long long code like

```
for i in range (0, 3) :
   A[0][1] = 1
```

And i wonder if there is a simpler Python-ic way

Comment: Could please add a example of what you really want? This question as it is, needs more details.

Comment: If you want to change the values at once, you have to make a list of values to be assigned and simply assign the list to A[0].

Comment: I am talking about something like...
values = [1,1,1] or values[1]*3 
and assign it like A[0] = values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do something like this.

```
A[0] = [1,1,1]
```

No need to iterate if you know the index.

Answer (score 1):

You may `j` index :

- either with a range `[1..3]`:

  ```
  A = [[j for i in range (3)] for j in range(1,4)]
  ```
- or range  `[0..2]` and use `j+1`

  ```
  A = [[(j+1) for i in range (3)] for j in range(3)]
  ```

Comment: Thank you for answer but let's just suppose the Array A has already been defined and values of A's are decided later.

Comment: @Jaehyun.Kim Do you want to keep some values of the existing array ? If not just create a new one with this my code

Comment: yes, i don't wanna create new array. I was wondering if i can change values in A[0][all] at once.

Comment: @Jaehyun.Kim this need to change all the values of the inner list, why just change the inner lists, this is shorter, and better than looping to change only the value, this is better to recreate one, why don't you want that ?